# Typecasting sockaddr structures

Tags: c, sockets, casting

I'm trying to learn network programming, and C in the process. I'm confused about the structures `sockaddr` which is a generic adress and `sockaddr_in`. My book has this to say:

> Thus, we can fill in the fields of a sockaddr_in and then cast (a
>   pointer to) it to a (pointer to a) sockaddr and pass it to the socket
>   functions, which look at the sa_family field to learn the actual type,
>   then cast back to the appropriate type.

But it doesn't seem to me that the two structs should be compatible? One has two fields,

```
struct sockaddr {
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char sa_data[14];
};
```

The other has plenty

```
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr;
};

struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t sin_family;
    in_port_t sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
    char sin_zero[8];
};
```

They both have size 16 in memory. I guess this is why they zero-pad the sockaddr_in structure, to enable casting? I'm still confused - can casting ever be meaningful if you don't immidiately cast back? Is it always just a temporary cast, utilizing the fact that the sa_family_t field resides in the first `N` bits?

Comment: For all things network related see [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It is an excellent reference/tutorial for network programming. It is only about **100%** applicable to your current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not requested to cast the `struct` but a pointer to it.

The relevant info for the underlying call, that is which `struct` is referenced, can be pulled from the `sin_family` member, which is available in any case.

So in essence the cast is just around to silence the compiler, as the function called expects a pointer to `struct sockaddr` but in fact gets passed a pointer to a different type.

Comment: "silence the compiler" Isn't this UB?

Comment: @usr: It only invokes undefined behaviour if the resulting pointer isn't correctly aligned. C11 Draft 6.3.2.3/7: "*A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined.*"

Comment: OK, creating the pointer might be allowed but dereferencing it is not as far as I know.

Comment: @usr: If the alignment is correct the pointer resulting from the conversion might very well be de-referenced. If this would not be allowed/possible the whole socket interface would be broken, though.